# Google Search with Alamofire Fails (iOS, Swift, JSON, HTML)

Tags: html, json, swift, alamofire, google-search

Please help! I'm stuck for months now trying to perform a simple **Google Search** on my Swift App and I'm way past smashing my head through the wall!

I've tried both with **ALAMOFIRE** and With a Regular URLRequest, but since the result seems to be only in HTML Format, I Can't seem to parse the results correctly. Even when you look into the HTML Format, the code is for a Webpage, and it does NOT Include the Search Results.

I Would LOVE to have the search Results into a Simple Dictionary. **Here is my Code:**

```
        let googleUrl:String = "https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?&output=json&cx=<MyGoogleKey>:<MyGoogleSKey>&q=q=+normal+search"

        // Trying with AlamoFire:

        Alamofire.request(googleUrl).response { response in
            print("Request: \(response.request)")
            print("Response: \(response.response)")
            print("Error: \(response.error)")
        }.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
             print("ResponseJSON: \(response)")
        }).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
              print("ResponseData: \(response)")
        }).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
              print("ResponseString: \(response)")
        })
```

As you See I Try the Response in almost ALL Alamofire supported Types and I GEt NOTHING.

Here is Error #1 (.**responseJSON**):

The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
ResponseJSON: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Here is DATA Response (.**responseData**):
ResponseData: SUCCESS: 4337 bytes

Here is the Response HTML (.**responseString**)

ResponseString: SUCCESS:

*>      Google Custom Search

> (function(){var cookie_path='/cse/';var
>   path_copy='/coop/';window._gaq =
>   window._ga...._AND_SO_ON_TILL_FULL_HTML_PAGE_IN_A_STRING....*

*** I Only wish I Could have the Search Results in a Simple Dictionary...**

Anyone? Please?

Comment: Are you using iOS 9 or 10. iOS 9 you have to be careful about the ATS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the Custom Search API for embedding into web pages.

This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest) is for what you want to do.

Here is an example using stack overflow as the search domain.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        search(query: "swift") { (results) in

            for result in results {

                dump(result)
            }
        }
    }

    func search(query:String, completion: @escaping (Array<SearchResult>)->()){

        let id = "Custom search engine ID"

        let key = "API key"

        let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=\(key)&cx=\(id)&q=\(query)"

        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in

            var results = Array<SearchResult>()

            if let dict = response.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {

                if let items = dict["items"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> {

                    for item in items {

                        if let result = SearchResult(dict: item) {

                            results.append(result)

                        } else {

                            print("Incomplete search result data.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            completion(results)
        }
    }
}
```

I have this struct to store the search results better. It doesn't contain all the values that the JSON results does. I just chose these ones for testing.

```
struct SearchResult {

    var displayLink: String

    var formattedUrl: String

    var htmlFormattedUrl: String

    var htmlSnippet: String

    var htmlTitle: String

    var link: String

    var snippet: String

    var title: String

    init?(dict:Dictionary<String,Any>) {

        guard

            let displayLink = dict["displayLink"] as? String,

            let formattedUrl = dict["formattedUrl"] as? String,

            let htmlFormattedUrl = dict["htmlFormattedUrl"] as? String,

            let htmlSnippet = dict["htmlSnippet"] as? String,

            let htmlTitle = dict["htmlTitle"] as? String,

            let link = dict["link"] as? String,

            let snippet = dict["snippet"] as? String,

            let title = dict["title"] as? String

        else {

            return nil
        }

        self.displayLink = displayLink

        self.formattedUrl = formattedUrl

        self.htmlFormattedUrl = htmlFormattedUrl

        self.htmlSnippet = htmlSnippet

        self.htmlTitle = htmlTitle

        self.link = link

        self.snippet = snippet

        self.title = title
    }
}
```

This is a couple of results that `dump(result)` prints out.

```
▿ CustomGoogleSearch.SearchResult
  - displayLink: "stackoverflow.com"
  - formattedUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift"
  - htmlFormattedUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<b>swift</b>"
  - htmlSnippet: "<b>Swift</b> is an open-source programming language developed by Apple. Use the tag <br>\nonly for questions about language features, or requiring code in <b>Swift</b>. Use the&nbsp;..."
  - htmlTitle: "Newest &#39;<b>swift</b>&#39; Questions - Stack Overflow"
  - link: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift"
  - snippet: "Swift is an open-source programming language developed by Apple. Use the tag \nonly for questions about language features, or requiring code in Swift. Use the ..."
  - title: "Newest \'swift\' Questions - Stack Overflow"

▿ CustomGoogleSearch.SearchResult
  - displayLink: "stackoverflow.com"
  - formattedUrl: "stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topics"
  - htmlFormattedUrl: "stackoverflow.com/documentation/<b>swift</b>/topics"
  - htmlSnippet: "58 example-focused documentation topics for <b>Swift</b> Language."
  - htmlTitle: "All <b>Swift</b> Language Topics - Stack Overflow"
  - link: "http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topics"
  - snippet: "58 example-focused documentation topics for Swift Language."
  - title: "All Swift Language Topics - Stack Overflow"
```

#### Getting the keys

On this [page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest), click the `Get A Key` button.

[image: Get API Key Button]

You then need to select or create a Google project, then you will be generated an API Key. So copy this an put in here `let key = "API key"`

For the Search Engine ID, go to your [console](https://cse.google.com/all). Now either select a search engine or create a new one. You'll get to a page like this.

[image: Google Custom Search Engine Settings Page]

Click the `Search engine ID` button, this will display a screen with your id, then put that here `let id = "Custom search engine ID"`

Comment: I Still haven't Tested it but it seems to be Acomplete Answer... You sure Deserve the Bounty :-)

Comment: Hi @Tristan Beaton, could you please Help me find the Correct API Key and the cx Field? I Think this is my real problem now... Cheers